# Grammar involving than

Tags: grammar

"It takes more data than is available. " 
Is this sentence grammatically correct? Should the sentence be modified to " it takes more data than it is available.  Are there any other examples that show something can be omitted after "than"?Also, does "than" function as a conjunction or proposition here? thanks

Comment: "Than" is a preposition. When it takes a clausal complement that clause is always reduced in some way relative to the structure of a main clause. Hence "it takes more data than [is available]" is fine as the reduced equivalent of *"it takes more data than [data is available]". Another example is "She did better in her exams than [we thought she would]"

Comment: The words inside the brackets the example you provided cannot be omitted altogether?

Comment: Your emendation _than it is available_ is actually ungrammatical. A dummy subject cannot be used in this case.

Comment: I agree with Colin, and sticking an extra "it" in a sentence like this is actually a very common error made by English learners.  It's confusing because you *do* put another "it" in a sentence like "It is wider than it is tall."

Comment: @user86756744708 No, they can't. They form a clause functioning as an **obligatory** complement of "than.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *It takes more data than* [*is available*].

"Than" is a preposition. When it takes a clausal complement in a **comparative** construction, that clause is always reduced in some way relative to the structure of a main clause. Hence "it takes more data than [is available]" is fine as the reduced equivalent of *"it takes more data than [data is available]".

Another example is

> *She did better in her exams than* [*we thought she would*].

Here, the complement of "would" is left understood. The meaning can be given as:

"She did *x* well in her exams; we thought she would do *y* well; *x* > *y*".

But the "y well" part cannot be syntactically overt.

Comment: thx for your response. Where can i find more about this structure? And how about "it takes more data than being available". I have seen many instances of gerund after proposition.

Comment: Haven't you misplaced the first bracket, Bill? Surely you wouldn't end the sentence with _than_.

Comment: No: the brackets surround the comparative clause functioning as complement of the prep "than". The complement is of course obligatory here.